# Event after option from dropdown menu is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

i have some data in data-attributes of dropdown menu options, and i need access to them, every time user picks one of the options. here's my html

Title

```
    <div class="input select optional poster_kind"><label class="select optional" for="poster_kind_id">Kind</label><select class="select optional" id="poster_kind_id" name="poster[kind_id]"><option role="kind" type="Category" value="1">Praca</option>
    <option role="kind" type="Subcategory" value="1">alfons</option>
    <option role="kind" type="Subcategory" value="2">dziwka</option>
    <option role="kind" type="Category" value="2">Handel</option>
    <option role="kind" type="Subcategory" value="3">koks</option>
    <option role="kind" type="Subcategory" value="4">meta</option></select></div>
```

i tried this approach

```
$('[data-role="kind"]').click ->
        kindType = $(this).data("type")
        $("[data-role='kind']").val(kindType)
```

but it is not working, nothing happens when i click on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected text try the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#poster_kind_id').change(function() {
        var idx = $("#poster_kind_id option:selected").text(); 
    var type= $("#poster_kind_id option:selected").attr("type");  // to get the type    
         alert(idx);
    });

    });
```

Comment: ok, nice, but how to get 'type' attribute out of it? .data("type") doesnt work:/

Answer (score 0):

you can use change event of the dropdown.just add a function and call it on the onchange event of the control

```
function SelectDropdown(){  
    var idx = $("#poster_kind_id option:selected").text();      
     alert(idx);
}
```